# How to show splash screen until tab bar is loaded in android

Tags: android

How do I show the splash screen until the tab bar is loaded in android? Can anybody give an example?

I have a login screen. From the login screen, if the user clicks the login button, I am getting data from the webservice and loading tab bar in an android activity at that time the screen will be black it takes time for the tabbar to load. I want to display the splash screen.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, splash screens have been widely discussed. In short: Don't. Secondly: What? Your question is very vague, to say the least. What setup do you have? What do you want to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just because some people feel load screens don't belong in Android doesn't make this an invalid question.  Upvote here to offset the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by applying a theme to the activity that you want to display the loading screen.

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/loadscreen</item>
</style>
```

and in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MyTabActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

your activity will now display the loadscreen drawable instead of a black screen while its loading.